# Difference between these two partition functions

Tags: c++, function, sorting

I literally could not understand whether there is a **difference** or not between them. By the way the functions are functions used for **partition**. The reason why I ask this is because I'm implementing a **merge sort** and with there first function below it does not work. Both written by but I simply cannot understand why the first one doesn't work

**First function;**

```
vector<int>partition(vector<int>vec,int start,int finish)
{
    vector<int>list;
    for(int i=start;i<finish;i++)
        list.push_back(vec[i]);
    return list;
}
```

**Second function;**

```
vector<int>partition(vector<int>vec,int start,int finish)
{
    vector<int>parted;
    int size=finish-start+1;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        parted.push_back(vec[i+start]);
    return parted;
}
```

Comment: There's an `std::partition` in `<algorithm>`. You can almost guarantee it will work better than anything you try to write.

Comment: They look roughly equivalent to me. Maybe you want `i <= finish`?

Comment: @chris I wasn't actually looking for a partition function but I'll keep that in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @jli I simply cannot understand. I just think the same but the first function does not work when I integrate it to my merge sort.

Comment: Yeah that is the only difference between the two. You need to do `i <= finish`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is that the first will not include `vec[finish]` in the output, while the second will.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your just copying a range from the vector, you can use std::copy for that. Also for good practice, pass by const-reference when possible. And as other have pointed out the difference between the two is that the first function treats finish as one pass the end while the second one includes it. Generally you might want to stay consistent and use the first one since it would be consistent with STL.